# D3 Library — How To Access Data from JSON in this example

Tags: d3.js

I didn't explain the issue properly in the title... Sorry.

I'm following the D3 Tag Cloud Simple example
https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/blob/master/examples/simple.html

I have a JSON file that consists of tweet tags, sentimental values and tweet text;
(excerpt)

```
var words = [{"word":"disgrace","sentiment":"0.975","tweet":"Wheres Fred the weatherman? \nIn jail #disgrace #dirtyman @MrJimmyCorkhill"},{"word":"dirtyman","sentiment":"0.975","tweet":"Wheres Fred the weatherman? \nIn jail #disgrace #dirtyman @MrJimmyCorkhill"}];
```

I want to use the "tweet" value as a 'title' element of each 'text' element.
I tried doing this by putting my tweet in the .words function (or .map, I don't know :s), as other data is accessed that way, but I can't extract my 'tweet' data;

```
var fill = d3.scale.category20();
var words = <?php echo $tweets->getTweetTags(); ?>;

d3.layout.cloud().size([1000, 1000])
.words(words.map(function(d) {
return {text: d.word, size: d.sentiment * 40, tweet: d.tweet};
}))
.rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * Math.random() * 1; })
.font("Impact")
.fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
.on("end", draw)
.start();

function draw(words) {
d3.select("#vis").append("svg")
.attr("width", 1000)
.attr("height", 1000)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(500,400)")
.selectAll("text")
.data(words)
.enter().append("text")
.style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
.style("font-family", "Impact")
.style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.attr("transform", function(d) {
return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
})
.text(function(d) { return d.text; })
.append("svg:title").text(function(d) { return d.tweet; } );
}
```

d.tweet returns undefined

I can probably understand why I can't use my tweet in the .words or .map function, as they only expect certain parameters, but I don't know how else to get the 'tweet' data into the 'title' tags of each 'text' element.

Can anyone help me with this?

**Edit:** Code with inside d3.json function;

```
var data; // a global
            d3.json("../../../assets/json/tweetTags.json", function(error, json) {
              if (error) return console.warn(error);
              data = json;

              var fill = d3.scale.category20();

              d3.layout.cloud().size([1000, 1000])
                  .words(data.map(function(d) {
                    return {text: d.word, size: d.sentiment * 40, tweet: d.tweet};
                  }))
                  .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * Math.random() * 1; })
                  .font("Impact")
                  .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
                  .on("end", draw)
                  .start();

              function draw(data) {
                d3.select("#vis").append("svg")
                    .attr("width", 1000)
                    .attr("height", 1000)
                  .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(500,400)")
                  .selectAll("text")
                    .data(words)
                  .enter().append("text")
                    .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
                    .style("font-family", "Impact")
                    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                      return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
                    })
                    .text(function(d) { return d.text; })
                    .append("svg:title").text(function(d) { return d.tweet; } );
              }

              d3.layout.cloud().size([300, 300])
              .data.map(function(d) {
                return {text: d, size: 10 + Math.random() * 90};
              })
              .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
              .font("Impact")
              .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
              .on("end", draw)
              .start();
            });
```

I don't know how to get it working in like that. I have made the json file but now I can't access the data or run the cloud.

**Edit:** The text elements are appending outside of the closing body tag now :(

```
var data; // a global
            d3.json("../../../assets/json/tweetTags.json", function(error, json) {
              if (error) return console.warn(error);
              data = json;

              var fill = d3.scale.category20();

             d3.select("#vis").append("svg")
                 .attr("width", 1000)
                 .attr("height", 1000)
                 .append("g")
                 .attr("transform", "translate(500,400)")
                 .data(json)
                 .enter().append("text")
                 .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.sentiment * 40 + "px"; })
                 .style("font-family", "Impact")
                 .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })

                 .text(function(d) {return d.word;})
                 .append("svg:title").text(function(d) { return d.tweet; } );

            });
```

**Edit: @Chris** This is your exampled code in the D3 json function and with my customisations

```
d3.json("../../../assets/json/tweetTags.json", function(error, json) {
  if (error) return console.warn(error);

  var fill = d3.scale.category20();

  d3.layout.cloud().size([600, 500])
      .words(json.map(function(d) {;
            return {text: d.word, size: d.sentiment * 40, tweet: d.tweet};
       }))
      .rotate(function(d) { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
      .font("Impact")
      .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
      .on("end", draw)
      .start();

  function draw(words) { 
      d3.select("body").append("svg")
          .attr("width", 600).attr("height", 500)
          .append("g").attr("transform", "translate(350,350)")
          .selectAll("text").data(words)
          .enter().append("text")
          .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
          .style("font-family", "Impact")
          .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
              return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
          })
          .text(function(d) { return d.text; }).append("svg:title")
          .text(function(d) { return d.tweet; } );
      }
})
```

But I can't access d.tweet from the draw function :s

Comment: You should accept an answer if you think your question has been successfully answered.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you should use the built-in [import function for json](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_json) instead of php. I think that the problem you have is that the reading of the data is asynchronous, so `words` is not filled before using it in clouds.

The principle behind `d3.json()` is to do everything in this function, which will be executed when the json is loaded:

```
var data; // a global
d3.json("path/to/file.json", function(error, json) {
  if (error) return console.warn(error);
  data = json;
  visualizeit();
});
```

**EDIT**

Here is an example of the code that should work, I just added the [d3 cloud example](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/blob/master/examples/simple.html) inside the json function.

```
d3.json("../../../assets/json/tweetTags.json", function(error, json) {
  if (error) return console.warn(error);

  var fill = d3.scale.category20();

  d3.layout.cloud().size([300, 300])    
      .words([  // To be replaced with data
        "Hello", "world", "normally", "you", "want", "more", "words",
        "than", "this"].map(function(d) {
            return {text: d, size: 10 + Math.random() * 90};
       }))
      .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
      .font("Impact")
      .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
      .on("end", draw)
      .start();

  function draw(words) {
      d3.select("body").append("svg")
          .attr("width", 300).attr("height", 300)
          .append("g").attr("transform", "translate(150,150)")
          .selectAll("text").data(words)
          .enter().append("text")
          .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
          .style("font-family", "Impact")
          .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
              return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
          })
          .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
      }
})
```

Then, when this version works you can just replace the `.words()` by:

```
.words(json.map(function(d) {
  return {text: d.word, size: d.sentiment * 40, tweet: d.tweet};
}))
```

Comment: I've edited the code (see above) to do everything inside the d3.json function, but am struggling to get it generating the cloud now :s

Comment: Well for this I can only advise you to begin with something simple and then add options to achieve the desired result. First hint, why do you draw two clouds? But if the problem is no longer with the json, you should ask other questions. Always try to have the simplest (and shortest) code possible to illustrate your problem, it often leads to solving your problem by yourself.

Comment: Yeah that second cloud at the bottom is a mistake. I'll spend more time looking into the problem; it's just you were available and I didn't want to throw away support by not rushing things.

Comment: I've used your code and customised it, but am experiencing the original issue of not being able to access the tweet data from the draw function  (see edit above - Edit: @Chris)

Comment: So it is the following line that doesn't work: `.append("svg:title").text(function(d) { return d.tweet; } );`?

Comment: That's right, that returns undefined. I can access d.text though, or d.size.

Comment: I don't know, you should ask another question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you extract other entries of your data? e.g. words and sentiment? 
Maybe you could try it like following code. If it works, you can change it to your codes.

```
var data; // a global
d3.json("path/to/file.json", function(error, json) {
  if (error) return console.warn(error);
  d3.select("#vis").append("svg")
    .data(json)
    .enter().append("text")
    .text(function(d) {return d.tweets;});
});
```

Comment: So I think you can change it to meet your requirements.You tried to use words.map(function(d){...}) is a little problem. Cause variable "words" is just a normal Object, it doesn't have map function in its prototype I think. It's glad to help you.

Comment: Really good help Lephix (not discounting help from Chris), but I don't know how to figure out why my 'text' elements are appending outside of the '/body' element http://snag.gy/ktb5h.jpg

Comment: Maybe you should re-select the element before you enter() new element into it. For example: d3.select("svg > g").data(json).append("text").....

Comment: Because too many methods chain will confuse what the object you are really dealing with...

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with the words going out of the svg container and i solved it by inserting a variable called origin that i put to (width/2) in the translate method. The border problems were caused by the fact that the alghorithm is made to keep them inside as long as you use the correct center ot the projection field for example: width=300, height=300 that means origin=150. I hope that helps you.