# How to fetch data from json file to draw a dynamic graph by using d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I want to make a dynamic graph by using d3.js but I do not know how to fetch data from a json file to make the dynamic charts or graph. Could you please introduce some samples of code for making graphs from json file NOT tsv,csv and other formats ?

Thanks :)

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045 and many other examples: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery. There is also an API documentation: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/API-Reference.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_json

[D3 Library — How To Access Data from JSON in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448482/d3-library-how-to-access-data-from-json-in-this-example)

Check these resources.