# d3.JS JSON data import - not in global scope

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a json:

```
{
    "temp_data": [10,15,20]
}
```

I am trying to import it:

```
var temp_data;
//Importing from JSON
if(true){
    d3.json("graph.json", function(error, graph) {
        if (error){
            throw error;
        }
        temp_data = graph.temp_data;
        console.log(temp_data);    //works
    });
}

console.log("temp: " + temp_data); //Does not work
```

Problem is, despite declaring temp_data as global variable, the second log is not showing data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D3 Library — How To Access Data from JSON in this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448482/d3-library-how-to-access-data-from-json-in-this-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback passed into `d3.json()` runs asynchronously: https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_json

This means your second console.log() actually runs *before* "graph.json" has been retrieved, and therefore before your global variable is populated.  You need to do your work with this data inside the callback instead.

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked the fact that d3.json is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some information to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37681769/5768908): if you wait just a little bit, you can use your `console.log` outside the callback:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Outside the callback: " + temp_data);
}, 1000);
```

Check this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/zTg6Y6KSVedIBT2tVCu9?p=preview

The reason for this was already explained in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37681769/5768908): being asynchronous, the code below `d3.json` runs almost immediately, that is, it doesn't wait for `d3.json` to finish.

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked the fact that d3.json is asynchronous.