# How to read the elements of a JSON object obtained using d3.json

Tags: json, d3.js

I have an index.html file with JavaScript code to do some visualizations using d3 for which I need to read the value of an element called total from a JSON object stored in a file called flare3.json. However the value of total is not right.

The part giving me the error is as follows:

```
Var ht=0;
d3.json ("flare3.json", function (error, flare) {  
 if (error)   
   throw error;  
   console.log(flare);  
   ht = flare.total;  
   console.log(ht);  
});
```

The output for console.log (flare) is

> Object { total: 2294 }

There is no output for console.log (ht).

The code I've used to save the JSON object to flare3.json:

```
int tot=2294;
JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
obj1.put("total", tot );
FileWriter file1 = new FileWriter("/Users/ksameera/d3js_projects/flare3.json",false);
file1.write(obj1.toString());
file1.close();
```

The code runs without any errors.

How to get the right value of the element 'total' in index.html?

Comment: Are you sure the second console.log is **inside** the `d3.json` function?

Comment: The console.log(ht) was outside d3.json. I re-executed the code and this time with console.log inside d3.json there is no output  and also no errors

Comment: Wait a minute, no output for a console.log? This is unlikely.

Comment: I understood my mistake. The elements can only be accessed inside d3.json is that right? Even if the variable I'm storing it in is global it's scope is only within d3.json()

Comment: Yes, that's correct. There are alternatives, some of them interesting and some of them very ugly, such as using `setTimeout`... check my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37681973/5768908) for instance.